# How to Select a filter for a DataGrid filter as default filter when the view is loaded?

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, datagrid

I'm trying to Select a filter for a DataGrid filter as default filter when the view is loaded
i have add to my Project Data Grid Filter Libraryfrom github https://github.com/basio/veropos/blob/master/Lib/DataGridFilterLibrary/Themes/Generic.xaml

```
    <Style.Resources>
        <support:EnumDisplayer Type="{x:Type support:FilterOperator}" x:Key="filterOperators">
            <support:EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="Undefined" DisplayString=""/>
            <support:EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="LessThan" DisplayString="&lt;"/>
            <support:EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="GreaterThan" DisplayString="&gt;"/>
            <support:EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="Equals" DisplayString="="/>    
            <support:EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="Like" DisplayString="" ExcludeFromDisplay="True"/>
            <support:EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="Between" DisplayString="" ExcludeFromDisplay="True"/>
            <support:EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="LessThanOrEqual" DisplayString="&lt;="/>
            <support:EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="GreaterThanOrEqual" DisplayString="&gt;="/>
        </support:EnumDisplayer>
```

and it work Super fine for my ,

Right now there is no filter selected from the list ,
but i want to Select filter "Equals" as default filter when the Project start up
EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="Equals" DisplayString= "=" .

How this can be done !!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change a single instance, then I suggest you create a style with a setter where you set the value of FilterCurrentData.Operator to Equals, and use that style on the column you're trying to filter.

Disclaimer: This is notepad code, but it should serve you as a guide:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridColumnFilter}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <support:EnumDisplayEntry EnumValue="Equals" DisplayString="=" x:Key="defaultFilterOperatorEquals" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="FilterCurrentData.Operator" Value="{StaticResource defaultFilterOperatorEquals}" />
</Style>
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for answering but i want to set "Equals" as default filter from the eum list when the view is loaded